# How do I place the limits of integration for double integrals?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

If I am given a double integral question like

$$\iint_D y\cos (xy) \,dA,$$

where

$$D = \{(x, y) \mid 2 \leq x\leq 3, 0\leq y\leq \pi/2\}.$$

The question is, how do I know the order of $dA$. Is it $(dxdy)$ or $(dydx)$. What is the general rule of thumb?
Secondly, how do I know where to place the limits of integration?
Is it
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \int_2^3 y\cos (xy) ?? $$ or is it
$$ \int_2^3 \int_{0}^{\pi/2} y\cos (xy) ?? $$

Answer (score 0):

**Tip** for order of $dA$ check at [this link](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/m408m/Display15-2-4.shtml).

Next, the **limits of integration** is easy to recognize thanks to [Fubini's Theorem](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/m408m/Display15-2-3.shtml).